# React import from parent directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am unable to import file from parent of project directory. To make things as simple as possible, I created new react-native project and file 'test.js' in a parent directory. I tried to import it with this code:

```
var Test = require('../test.js');
```

and

```
import Test from ('../test.js');
```

None of these worked - when run in xcode I have following error:

> uncaught error Error: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module
>   ../test.js from /Users/UserName/Downloads/TestReact/index.ios.js:
>   Invalid directory /Users/UserName/Downloads/test.js

Is it possible to import file from parent directory with react-native?  I̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶c̶t̶J̶S̶.

Regards

edit - adding code

test.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component,View,Text} from 'react-native';

  class Test extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        SAMPLE TEXT
      </Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = Test;
```

index.ios.js

```
'use strict';
import React, {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import Test from '../test.js';

var TestReact = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View><Test/></View>
    );
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestReact', () => TestReact);
```

edit - added files hierarchy:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63MAQ.jpg)

edit - actually I was wrong, it's impossible with web react too. When I try to build I got following error:

> Module parse failed:
>   /path_to_file/aaa1.js Line 1:
>   Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
>   file type.

So adding react tag to the question.

Comment: It should definitely work like you have it. Can you post your code from test.js ? Thanks.

Comment: @NaderDabit But I believe content of test.js doesn't even matter, this error occurs even when I put there something as simple as `export default var a = 10;`

Comment: Could you add a file/directory hierarchy? And also i think this is not main mistake but, anyway _text.js_ you named it instead on _test.js_

Comment: @nAz added, again thanks for input.

Comment: Have you tried to put a _test.js_ file into your _TestReact_ folder? it should work definitely.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I want to have subfolder with react-native files in reactjs app directory. And it turned out to be impossible to import from parent directory and share some files between projects.

Comment: Use require
like

var Test = require( ' ../Test.js ');

and then Use Test as <Test />

Comment: @PramodMg Unfortunetly, as I already wrote in my post, that didn't work either..

Answer (score 13):

Try this `./../Component.js`. It works for me.
More over if you need access a component from adjacent directory `./../AdjDir/Component.js`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me--the default resolvers know how to handle relative directories whether you start with the current or parent directory. It's more likely the OP's config was broken, but almost everything is different than it was three years ago anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton yep, it was many years ago and I didn't manage to solve this issue. I don't know about current version of react native, but I'm still getting upvotes from time to time .

Answer (score 11):

This problem may be because react only allows you to import from the src folder. So all resources have to placed in this directory.

Also when you go more than two parent directories back you need to use this syntax:
../../../myfolder/myFile.js
[image: going back 2 parent directories]

Comment: React supports loading from anywhere, but not Create-React-App in your example.

Answer (score 5):

finally a stack overflow question I can answer:

Simply add below jsconfig.json to the base route of your react folder. (Assuming you put all of your react code in "src" folder)

```
example_react_app
  ---> public
  ---> src
  ---> jsconfig.json
```

jsconfig.json file content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I looks fine to me . Did you tried with just

```
import Test from '../test';
```

instead of

```
 import Test from '../test.js';
```

And also try without small bracket "( )";

I solved my issue with this. Hope it helps.