# Import files from parent directory into React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a file hierarchy as follows:

```
-native
   -app
      -components
          login.js
-redux
    -modules
        -users.js
```

In my login.js file, I attempt to import the users.js redux into my code as such:

```
import { actions as usersActions} from "../../../redux/modules/users";
```

It is shared code and I cannot put the redux code in native/ 
The error I get is:

```
Unable to resolve module ../../../redux/modules/users. ... Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories.
```

I've looked at the other questions, such as: [React import from parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937726/react-import-from-parent-directory) but in the comments it states it to be impossible. I've also tried the fixes in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 but that seems to be mostly for node-modules.

Answer (score -2):

Try creating a symbolic link inside the native directory that references the parent directory

Comment: If I put a symlink for the redux/ folder in components/ what would that change to allow me to import? Its just a different path

Comment: yes, but it would be inside the project tree, anyways I tried it and it seems watchman does not support symlink neither https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/105 at the end of the thread this tool is suggested https://github.com/wix/wml maybe works for your case

Comment: Would being inside the project tree change anything fundamentally about the way React Native imports the files? I don't see why it should make a difference, aside from lack of watchman support

Comment: I think is because the packager

Comment: I found this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-163567498