# import files from parent/other directory in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, importerror

How do I **import** files from the parent/other directories in my react project?
I want to import images from the `images` folder but I ran into an error
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg'.`

My Project Structure:

```
-- src
   ==> assets
        --> Images --> "Web_SVG.svg" (Image I want to import)

   ==> components
        --> pages
            - Home.js (File I'm working on)

   ==> Other Files (index.js, App.js, etc)
```

I tried a few solutions from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937726/react-import-from-parent-directory)
But it's not working for me.

Code for Home.js

```js
import React from 'react';

//Importing Img
import { img } from '../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex bg-red-50">
                <div>
                    <img src={img} alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: `import img from '../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg';` ?

Comment: If I'm understanding the folder structure you've outlined, shouldn't you be going up **two** directories? i.e. `../../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg`. Also you shouldn't be using the named import with curly braces, should just be `import img from ...`. Plus make sure whatever you're using to build the app has a loader for `.svg` files

Comment: @Jayce444 I am not aware of SVG loader, can you explain it or drop an article/link.  Also you are right, I changed `../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg` to `../../assets/images/Web_SVG.svg` , the PNGs are working fine but I want to use SVG